# How do I insert all my shapes into an array?

Tags: java, arrays, user-interface, javafx, javafx-8

I am Trying to build a cinema booker, where I have to select the seats. I was thinking about make placing all my rectangles in an array so i could use it for later, when clicking on a seat it should check if left and right seats are booked. Here the array index should help me. However I cant figure out how to get to this stage. (See picture.)

Take this scenario:
You click on a rectangle (representing a seat). It changes color only it is not Red colored. So Seats[][].checkNeighbourColor or something like that.[See picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IAeP3.png)

```
package sample;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.awt.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class Main extends Application {

private int seats = 12;
private int rows = 8;
private static Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize(); //gets screen resolution data





public static void main(String[] args) {
    Application.launch(args);

}

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    primaryStage.setTitle("");
    Group root = new Group();
    Scene scene = new Scene(root, screenSize.getWidth()/4, screenSize.getHeight()/3, Color.WHITE);


    for (int i = 0; i<= seats; i++)
    {
        Rectangle r = new Rectangle();
        r.setFill(Color.GREEN);
        r.setX(scene.getWidth()/5+i*30);
        r.setY(scene.getHeight()/5);
        r.setWidth(screenSize.getHeight()/80);
        r.setHeight(screenSize.getHeight()/80);
        root.getChildren().add(r);

        for (int q = 0; q<=rows; q++)
        {
            Rectangle s = new Rectangle();
            s.setFill(Color.GREEN);
            s.setX(scene.getWidth()/5+i*30);
            s.setY(scene.getHeight()/5+q*30);
            s.setWidth(screenSize.getHeight()/80);
            s.setHeight(screenSize.getHeight()/80);
            root.getChildren().add(s);


            s.setOnMouseClicked(event ->{
                s.setFill(Color.BLACK);
            });

        }
    }



    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

}

Comment: Is there a reason you are doing the `awt` import?

Comment: Why not use `GridPane`? This will eliminate the need for an array.

Comment: How to use `JavaFX` to get screen size: http://java-buddy.blogspot.com/2013/11/get-screen-size-using-javafxstagescreen.html

Comment: I'm not sure about your problem. You're having problems creating a multi-dimension vector to store your seats?

Comment: @RicardoGodoy Yes.

Comment: @SedrickJefferson how do i do that

Comment: And the awt thing is a mistake

Comment: James_D's answer should do the trick.

Comment: @SedrickJefferson Yea but I already tried that before. It gives me a runtime error: xception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not entirely clear to me what you're asking, but can't you just do

```
private Rectangle[][] rectangles = new Rectangle[seats][rows];
```

and then just do

```
rectangles[i][q] = s ;
```

For your listener you can do

```
final int row = i ;
final int seat = q ;
s.setOnMouseClicked(event -> {
    // check rectangles[row-1][seat] and rectangles[row+1][seat] as needed,
    // checking for range of row first
});
```

Aside: don't mix AWT and JavaFX. Use the [`Screen` API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/stage/Screen.html) to get the dimension of the physical screen(s) in JavaFX.

Comment: I just wanted to store my "seats" in an ordered sequence, so when ever I call my s.setOnMouseClicked(event -> {. It should get the index of the object i clicked on and check the index behind and infront. This I will use to check the colors.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I found my mistake. It was a simple ArrayOutOfBound (The statement in my for-loops was wrong), but thank you all for your help :)